# Which hyperledger fabric chaincode methods are actual transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Looking at the marbles example from the fabric samples, specific at the node.js version of the chaincode in the **marbles_chaincode.js** file, the function `async getAllResults(iterator, isHistory)` is clearly a helper function and not an actual transaction (at least this is what I could understand from looking at the code). Which functions are proper transactions and which are just helper methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct, getAllResults is just a helper function. This particular example isn't the best sample in the world and doesn't obviously distinguish which are transactions that can be called and which are helper methods. You need to understand the code to determine which are transactions. For example because the code uses a generic dispatcher implementation call the right method from an invoke you can eliminate all methods that don't follow the exact same signature of (stub, args, thisClass) then it isn't meant to be externally called. However that doesn't guarantee this but helps to at least provide an initial subset

Answer (score -1):

For actual transactions, we have to use **stub.putState** so that we can update the ledger. For query any data we have to use stub.getState where query is not considered as transaction because there is no update in ledger due to query.

So in Hyperledger Fabric, transactions are happened with the changes of world state of ledgers or invoking the chaincode and so we use **stub.putState** to put new information on ledger.

So if you find **stub.putState** in any function, you can consider that function as   proper transaction function.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't technically true. For example you may have a helper function that does the putState for you, also callable transactions don't have to call putState at all.